# Why is Arial Bold condensing in my Illustrator CC?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, fonts, text, character-styles

After an update, Arial Bold is displaying condensed while all other varieties of Arial are working as expected. Any ideas on why this would be happening?

[image: **capture**]

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure what you mean by an "update." I know that Microsoft removed some of the previously included typefaces from Windows 10. If you are using a Windows computer, and have recently updated to a newer version of Windows, it might be that included fonts no longer include the version of Arial that you had been using.  The Arial that is currently installed may no longer have a "bold" option, but instead have a number of different weights, like Medium, Strong, Black, etc..  I don't do much in Illustrator with typefaces, but I know in InDesign, if I have text that is formatted using the bold button, and I change to a typeface that requires me to choose a specific weight, I will get error messages and funny looking type, like what you are seeing.

Comment: oh... I meant I updated illustrator cc. On my font list arial bold is missing... huh I guess bold is no longer an option?https://ibb.co/i6Ejqa

Comment: That's definitely what is showing in the image you included, but that doesn't make sense--if you are seeing those other versions of Arial, Arial Bold should be one of the options.  I am using CC2017 and it shows on my computer. https://ibb.co/g2EvwF  I know that you just upgraded, but have you tried rebooting your computer and/or re-setting your Illustrator preferences?  It looks like one of those "who knows why it happens, just start over again" problems.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem today in my Illustrator and PS and was searching for some answers, but none of those helps. So, by any chance that you still haven't found the answers all I did is I delete the font Antenna Bold. It's similar to the Arial Bold and I think it conflicts with it that why it will appear as condensed. Anyway hope this helps.

Comment: You're a life-saver!!
I had this blasted problem with Arial Bold on my new computer. It was an Illustrator file I had created on my older soon-to-retire computer. For days I couldn't figure out why Arial Bold of all things, a font that comes with the system, was appearing extremely condensed! Lo and behold you had the perfect solution. Antenna was one of the fonts I installed on the new comp and this was never installed on the old computer & it didn't occur to me to be in conflict with Arial Bold.
Uninstalled Antenna and that fixed the issue with Arial Bold.
Thank you!